# Functions not able to find variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following variable `$user_id` being set by

```
    //Check if user is logged in
session_start();
   if (!isset ($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    header("location:login.php");     
} 
 elseif(isset ($_SESSION['user_id']))
  {
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  }
```

and then within the same function file I have the following:

```
function course_menu()
  {
      $sqlSubscription = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'";
            $subscriptionResult = mysql_query($sqlSubscription);

                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($subscriptionResult))
                    {
                        $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
                        $course_id = $rows['course_id'];
                        $course_title = $rows['course_title'];

                              if ($data_id == $rows['course_id'])

                              {
                                  echo
                                  '<li>
                                      <a href="chapters.php?course_id=',$course_id,'&course_name=',$course_title,'" class="active">',$course_title,' </a>
                                          </li>';
                              }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      echo          
                                                  '<li><a href="chapters.php?course_id=',$course_id,'&course_name=',$course_title,'">',$course_title,' </a></li>';
                                  }
                    }
  }
```

The problem is I keep getting undefined variable user_id every time I try to run the function. I can `echo $user_id` on another page lets say `index.php` by using `require_once function.php` and then `echo $user_id`, but for some reason the function itself can't access it?

I think it might be because it's outside its scope - but if so I'm not entirely sure what to do about it.

My question is, how can I get the function to be able to use the variable $user_id?

**EDIT**

So I've started doing

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
global $conn;

$sqlSubscription = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'";
            $subscriptionResult = $conn->query($sqlSubscription);
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subscriptionResult))
                {
                    $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
                    $course_id = $rows['course_id'];
                    $course_title = $rows['course_title'];

                          if ($data_id == $rows['course_id'])

                          {
                              echo
                              '<li>
                                  <a href="chapters.php?course_id=',$course_id,'&course_name=',$course_title,'" class="active">',$course_title,' </a>
                                      </li>';
                          }
                              else
                              {
                                  echo          
                                              '<li><a href="chapters.php?course_id=',$course_id,'&course_name=',$course_title,'">',$course_title,' </a></li>';
                              }
                }
```

which seems to work fine, but it's a bit tedious to add a new connection each time with a function or set the $user_id manually. Is there any way around this as I have several functions that require a connection to the db to pull data. Is there a better way to structure this type of stuff? I'm not very familiar with OOP but I can try it out if I can get some direction, here's another function that I use (and there are at least another 5-6 that require db connections)

```
function render_dashboard()
{
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
global $conn;
//Following brings up the number of subscription days left on the user dashboard
$sqlDate = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'" ;
$date = $conn->query($sqlDate);

 while ($daterows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($date))
                    {
                        $course_registered = $daterows['course_title'];
                        $date_time = $daterows['end_date'];
                        $calculate_remaining = ((strtotime("$date_time")) - time())/86400;
                        $round_remaining = round("$calculate_remaining", 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                       // Here we assign the right term to the amount of time remaining I.E DAY/DAYS/EXPIRED
                         if($round_remaining > 1)
                             {
                                 $remaining = $course_registered." ".$round_remaining." "."Days Remaining";
                                 $subscriptionStatus = 2;
                                 echo '<p>',$remaining,'</p>';
                             }

                        elseif ($round_remaining == 1) 
                             {
                                 $remaining = $course_registered." ".$round_remaining." "."Day Remaining";
                                 $subscriptionStatus = 1;
                                 echo '<p>',$remaining,'</p>';
                             }

                        elseif ($round_remaining <= 0) 
                            {
                                  $remaining = $course_registered." "."Expired"." ".$date_time;
                                  $subscriptionStatus = 0;
                                   echo '<p>',$remaining,'</p>';
                            }


                    }

//Check for most recent viewed video
 $sqlVideo = "SELECT `last_video` FROM users WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'" ;
 $videoResult = $conn->query($sqlVideo);
 if ($videoRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($videoResult))
 {
     $last_video = $videoRows['last_video'];
     $videoLink = "SELECT `chapter_id` FROM chapters WHERE `chapter_title` = '".$last_video."'";
     if ($chapteridResult = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($videoLink)));
     {
     $chapter_id = $chapteridResult['chapter_id'];
     }

     $videoLink = "SELECT `course_id` FROM chapters WHERE `chapter_title` = '".$last_video."'";
     if ($courseResult = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($videoLink)));
     {
     $course_id = $courseResult['course_id'];
     }
 }


}
```

Comment: Put $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id']; inside your function.

Comment: are you using nested functions.?

Comment: @sskoko, thank you this worked - is there an alternative to doing it this way? I updated the post with some more information

Comment: I guess you could pass it to the function: render_dashboard($_SESSION['user_id']);

Comment: Never use `global`.  In fact, forget you know that it exists.  Functions and methods have arguments lists (the part with the parentheses right after the function/method name) specifically to address this very problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to getting around it without using global is to either DEFINE and pass it through ie - `define ('var', '$var')` `then function x($var)` or dependency injection as stated here [How can I use "Dependency Injection" in simple php functions, and should I bother?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255771/how-can-i-use-dependency-injection-in-simple-php-functions-and-should-i-bothe)

Answer (score 2):

The function **`course_menu()`** will not recognize your **`$user_id`**, Since it is outside its scope.

Make use of **`global`** keyword to solve this issue.

```
function course_menu()
  {
   global $user_id;
   // your remaining code .........
```

Comment: this worked for me thanks, I updated my post with some more information. Is there a way I can set it up so I don't have to set a global and new connection for every single function?

Comment: `global` is never, ever, *ever* the right way to go.  The argument list exists for a reason.  I'm dismayed that this had 3 upvotes before I got here.

Comment: @Fahad, create **one** connection and pass it into your functions via their argument lists.  `global` is exactly the wrong way to approach, well, just about everything in PHP.  It leads to tightly coupled, poorly designed code.